# Proving that every smooth manifold is metrizable

Tags: metric-spaces, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I'm trying to prove that every smooth manifold is metrizable. The outline of my proof looks like this:

1. By the Whitney Embedding Theorem, we can embed any smooth manifold $M$ into $\mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$ for some $n$.
2. This embedded submanifold inherits a topology from $\mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$ generated by balls defined using the standard Euclidean distance metric. Thus, $M$ is metrizable.

Is that all that's needed? It almost seems too simple.

Comment: Yes, any subspace of a metric space is itself a metric space. In fact, you can prove it for topological (rather than smooth) manifolds by using more point-set topology. It follows, for example, from the Urysohn metrization theorem (if you assume manifolds are second countable).

Comment: Well, the Whitney Embedding Theorem is not that simple. If you are willing to use hard theorems, many statements become "simple".

Comment: If you allow the existence of Riemannian metrics (which is a straight-forward partition of unity construction anyway) on a manifold $M$, then you can make sense of the length of a path $\gamma\colon [0,1]\to M$ between two points $p,q \in M$ -- it is just defined to be $$\ell(\gamma) = \int_{0}^{1} \|\gamma'(t)\|dt$$. Once you have a notion of the length of a path, you can check that $d(p,q) = \inf_{\gamma: \gamma(0)=a,\gamma(1)=b}\{\ell(\gamma)\}$ gives a distance function on $M$ so that $M$ is a metric space.